# How can you set in code the ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled for a datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer

I would like to set this in C# but I cannot access the property.

Comment: `ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"`  [#1,005 – Enabling Deferred Scrolling for Better Performance](http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/scrollviewer/)

Comment: That's an attached property. Use syntax like described [here](http://10rem.net/blog/2012/03/29/xaml-tip-setting-attached-properties-from-code).

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in C# by using its attached property

```
ScrollViewer.SetIsDeferredScrollingEnabled(DataGrid,false);
```